# java method retrieves 

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I need to send collection to this method:

```
public boolean[] save(T... entities) {
    return _saveOrUpdateIsNew(entities);
}
```

and I tried to pass the collection:

```
List<Client> clientsToUpdate = new ArrayList<Client>();
save(clientsToUpdate );
```

but I get a compilation error that the method type is not applicable for `List<Client>`

**EDITED:**

After I added the line:

```
clientsToUpdate.toArray(new Client[0]);
```

I have this compilation error:

```
The method save(Client...) in the type BaseDAO<Client,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Client[])
```

Comment: Please show us the exact signature of the method, the exact call site and the exact error message, not some vague descriptions. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what that code is.  Can you post a complete example?

Comment: can you please keep cursor on compilation error and tell me exact error?

Comment: How about you post the compilation error too, and some more code.

Comment: Please add the compilation error

Comment: To all! I updated my question. I know it's weird

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method you mentioned is using varargs, it means it accepts a single `Client` instance or an array of `Client` objects. You should convert your `List` to array like this:

```
List<Client> clientsToUpdate = new ArrayList<Client>();
Client[] clients = clientsToUpdate.toArray(new Client[0]);
save(clients);
```

This should work unless you have multiple `Client` classes in your project.

Comment: I get: The method save(Client...) in the type BaseDAO<Client,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Client[])

Comment: I saw you previously mixed my answer with an other one...Mine works, unless you have multiple `Client` classes in your project...

Comment: you are right! I am sorry I had multiple client classes in my workspace which made it. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad to help! I wonder why I got a downwote with a correct and accepted answer without any explanation...

Comment: I can upvote it again - but please first you have to edit your answer otherwise it's locked. I thought that it's not correct and it was similar to a below answer

Answer (score 1):

T.. is not a collection, it's an array. So, you have to convert it. Perhaps with something like this:

```
for(Object o: T)
    myCollection.add(o);
```

EDIT:

Oh sorry, I think you want the different way. If you want to pass a Collection to your method, convert it to an array:

```
Object[] array = myCollection.toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass any Collection to vararg method (unless method signature is (Collection...), but that's almost certainly not what you want here) . Try with Array.